# Noise Robust Linear Prediction

Tags: noise, linear-prediction

So it appears that Linear Prediction as performed via Durbin Recursion is sensitive to additive noise. What are some techniques for linear prediction that may be more robust? Can anyone supply a link that discusses the noise sensitivity of linear prediction?

I am trying to perform inverse filtering of a voiced speech signal by finding the linear prediction coefficients. It honestly doesn't work too bad, even in the presence strong pink or brown noise, but I have a feeling there are some more robust ways to get these coefficients.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at [**this article**](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.59.1279&rep=rep1&type=pdf)?

Comment: I have not seen that one, but I just read through it. It is quite simple. I could implement the moving average filter in the time domain as well. One thing a reference of the article did bring up: That an ARMA Model may be more appropriate. Has anyone tried using an ARMA model to estimate the spectral envelope?